Service classes that only forward to DAO
I've seen service classes that do nothing except forwarding calls to DAO classes. E.g. userService.save(user) would simply call userDao.save(user)
I heard the argument that some day in the future, a service class may do a bit of extra lifting and call more than one DAO. Also, any DTO to entity mapping should also be at the service layer (and not in the controller)
However, in my current project, a desktop Swing application, we don't have any of that. Instead, we have some unseemly hybrids of entity and DAO that store the data (in public fields) and persist it as well. E.g. the DEPARTMENT class matches the DEPARTMENT DB table and both stores the values of the associated table row and communicates with the DB. So, for example, updating the table data may look something like this
new DEPARTMENT().setId(id).setName(newName).UPDATE();

Such classes should obviously be split into at least entity and DAO classes
But should we add another, service layer that would (I guess) only forward to DAO classes and nothing else?
Our table count is great, and few people know the real number. But it's in the thousands

I've worked in four projects, where the largest problem was lack of separation between persistence layer and business logic. Never again!

This way you are separating the responsibilities between several layers and by wrapping DAO methods by Service - think the access to DB is business logic as well, even doe there are no complex rules.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
